# CHECK: For each of the following permutations $\rho$ in $S(6)$ write $\rho$ as the product of disjoint cycles:

Tags: group-theory

For each of the following permutations $\rho$ in $S(6)$ write $\rho$ as the product of disjoint cycles:

1. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4
       & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$
2. $[\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 &
       3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6
       \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 &
       4 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}$

Part 1:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 6 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
= & \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 4 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3 \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Part 2:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& [\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1} \\
= & \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 5 & 6 & 3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 3 & 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \\
= & \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 6 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

attempt 2:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& [\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1} \\
= & [\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 3 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 1   \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 1 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1} \\
= &  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \\
= & \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 5 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1 & 6 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Are these correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Part a:}$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
= \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 6 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
= & \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 4 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 3 \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

$\textbf{Part b:}$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& [\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 6 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1} \\
= & [\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 3 & 2 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 1 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1} \\
= & [\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}[\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}]^{-1} \\
= & \begin{pmatrix} 6 & 4 & 5 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 6 & 4 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \\
= & \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 6 & 3 & 5 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

I like your answer for part a but for b I get (1)(2 5 6 3)(4)

Comment: Is your work the same as mine?

Comment: I re-did it and I got the following which I posted above